# Is it possible to automate the crafting or repair of Tinkers' Construct tools?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I'm playing Agrarian Skies v 3.1.4 (Minecraft 1.6.4) which includes Tinkers' Construct and Iguana Tweaks (which adds XP to tools).

I'm using Autonomous Activators and Vacuum Hoppers to automate the accumulation of XP on Tinkers' Construct tools in order to a) mass-produce high-end, high-level tools for other players on the server, and b) to proc unusual combinations of modifiers (e.g. triple-Reinforced in order to craft Reinforced X tools).

Currently I'm using AE precision buses to insert new tools into the AA, and to extract broken ones. However, ideally, I'd like to automate the entire process including crafting and repair.

Is it possible to automate the Tool Forge and/or Crafting Station so that the crafting of Tinkers' Construct tools can be fully automated?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can automate the tool forge or crafting station, but, you don't have to.

Iguana's Tinker Tweaks adds the ability to repair tools in a crafting grid with just tool+material. You could use a liquicrafter to fix the tools. You have to set up the pattern or template for each specific tool, but at least it's some automation.

A ME crafting matrix works most of the time but needs a pattern encoded for each level of the tool. liquicrafter won't break like that. I don't know what other auto-crafters might do.

I tested the repairing in Agrarian Skies 3.1.2 and it worked.